# How to make Hibernate to use SequenceHiLoGenerator for JPA GenerationType.AUTO on Oracle?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with id like below, but hibernate uses org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator instead of SequenceHiLoGenerator for GenerationType.AUTO, how can I tell hibernate to use SequenceHiLoGenerator?

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="admin_seq", sequenceName="unique_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="admin_seq")
private Long id
```

If I use GenerationType.SEQUENCE, hibernate will use SequenceHiLoGenerator, but I need to use GenerationType.AUTO for compatibility with MySQL.

I have tried using @GenericGenerator, it works for Oracle but will be complained by MySQL: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect does not support sequences.

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "admin_seq", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "unique_id"),
                @Parameter(name = "max_lo", value = "50") })
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="admin_seq")
private Long id
```

I also tried using SequenceStyleGenerator by setting hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true in hibernate properties. It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true` which uses `SequenceStyleGenerator`, it would work with Oracle. We have similar configuration in our project which works fine.

If you want to achieve bulk id retrieval(like 50 each time) to speed up the `persist/save`, the quirk here  is you need to set `allocationSize` to 50 and also set your sequence `Increment By` to 50. 50 here is just a random number I choose, if you have massive persist, you can assign larger number. The most important thing here is the `allocationSize` in code and the `Increment By` in Database should **MATCH**.

The Oracle sql is something like

```
ALTER SEQUENCE YOUR_SEQUENCE_NAE INCREMENT BY 50;
```

The JPA entity ID field is like:

```
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "YOUR_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "SEQ_YOUR_ID",  allocationSize=50)
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "YOUR_ID_GEN")
        @Column(name = "YOUR_ID")
        public Long getYourId() {
            return this.yourId;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`strategy = GenerationType.AUTO` should work against MySQL with an identity column even though you've configured a sequence too. The sequencegenerator will be used when running against Oracle, but ignored when running against MySQL.

In your `persistence.xml` you should also switch your `hibernate.dialect` property between the correct values for a Oracle dialect and a MySQL dialect.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Yes, GenerationType.AUTO works for both Oracle and MySQL as you said. But for Oracle, it doesn't use SequenceHiLoGenerator, instead it uses simple SequenceGenerator which will hit Oracle DB to query the next sequence value on every new id. I worry it could cause performance issue.